# Xamarin iOS: Build and deploy app with error message - One or more errors occurred

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Using:

- Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.15 (Windows).
- XCode version 10.1
- tested on iPhoneX (iOS 13.1.1)

I try build and deploy iOS project, with no reason I getting error message - **One or more errors occurred**.  When I click on the error message, it brings me to this line of code.

```
<CopyFilesToBuildServer SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)" Files="@(_CopyFilesToMacOutput);@(_NoneWithCopyToOutputDirectory)" />
```

This error only happened when I select **Debug** mode, **Release** mode works good. I really have no ideas what had happened, many thanks to someone that could give me some ideas.

[image]

Comment: You can firstly delete the folder `bin` and `obj` , then clean and rebuild the project .

Comment: Tested with no luck

Comment: You can update the IDE to VS 2019 and check if the issue still appears .

Comment: Right click your project ->property->iOS build ->Link Behavior and make sure the value is **Don't Link**  .

Comment: check build configuration, perhaps you need to select more architectures to build for.

Comment: Were u able to figure it out?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Same error happened if I set link behavior to Don't Link. Fyi, my colleague with same version of Visual Studio 2017 able to build and run iOS. Did you have any ideas?

Comment: Try to uninstall your IDE and install it again .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issues with this steps:

(1) Update Visual Studio 2017 to latest version.

(2) Repair Visual Studio 2017.

(3) Clone again my project into different folder.

(4) Clean, build, run the project.